# Why does an MVC view need to exist in the View directory to work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewbag

I have been writing a cms with MVC being used as the main engine for generating the pages.

I am going well, but wanted the ability to create a unique razor template per site and possibly per view if I need to.

My rules are that each project has to have a unique code which is linked with a url.

Assets for each project site are stored in a way that the location relates to the project.

So an assets associated with project C0001 would be stored in `assets\C0001\` and for C0002: `assets\C0002\` and so on.

What I wanted to do, to keep things tidy, was to have the razor templates associated with a project located in the `assets\[ProjectCode]` location too, but the problem is I am getting an error about `ViewBag not existing in context`.

So this won't work:

```
Layout = string.Concat("~/assets/",ViewBag.ProjectNumber,"/_Layout.cshtml");
```

Where as the following will render a page:

```
Layout = string.Concat("~/Views/Shared/_",ViewBag.ProjectNumber,"Layout.cshtml");
```

I am guessing the first layout doesnt render,  because it is outside of the known search areas for views? But as I am telling it where the file is, I dont see what the problem is?

I am happy to work using the code in example 2, but could mean after a fair number of project sites the Shared views diretory will become very busy.

Just wondering if there is a reason why Views need to exist in the `Views` Directory?

Comment: @marcind: your right, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to copy the web.config that is located in your `Views` directory and put the copy in your `Assets` directory.   Since you need to supply a full path for layouts this is not a search path issue, it needs the info in the web.config to initialise the view properly.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, it has stopped rendering the css, but the view display so that is a step in the right direction.

Comment: With the web.config in place, it won't serve the css files from these directories (I haven't figured out why).  So unfortunately you'll need to pu the css in a separate directory tree

Comment: Got this working; find and change the httphandler, so the verb shows the following: `<add path="*" verb="*.cshtml" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>` so it will only look for the view files, leaves the rest alone

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `RazorViewEngine` is configured to look in the `Views` directory.

You can change this by creating your own `RazorViewEngine` instance with different paths and adding it to `ViewEngines.Engines`.

Its default paths are

```
AreaViewLocationFormats = new[] {
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};
AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[] {
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};
AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[] {
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};

ViewLocationFormats = new[] {
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};
MasterLocationFormats = new[] {
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};
PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] {
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I needed. When I registered a custom instance of `RazorViewEngine` in `Global.asax#Application_Start()`, I even got intellisense support for my custom view paths.  Very helpful.