# Specifying Layout From Another File Gives Compilation Errors (ASP.NET MVC3/Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor

I have a standard ASP.NET MVC3 application. In _ViewStart.cshtml, I used to have:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Everything worked, and life was good. Now, I want to move the layout to a directory that's modifiable at runtime; something like:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Content/Themes/" + SomeClass.FolderName + "_/Layout.cshtml";
}
```

(Where potentially I would call `SomeClass.FolderName = "blah"` in my code.)

Pasting a copy of the old `Shared/_Layout.cshtml` into the directory specified by `SomeClass.FolderName` unfortunately gives me several compilation errors, such as `ViewBag`, `Url`, and `Html` not existing (but strangely enough, `User.Identity` is still accessible).

What am I missing, and how can I make this work?

**Edit:** Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889062/why-does-an-mvc-view-need-to-exist-in-the-view-directory-to-work), I pasted my web.config from /Views into the directory, and it seems to work -- but a CSS file referenced gives me a 404 (eg. {SomeClass.FolderName}/site.css).

Comment: One specific error: `The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The MVC template configures Razor for MVC views in `~/Views/Web.config`](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-3-razor-and-mvc.html).
You need to copy the Razor section in Web.config to the other folder.

Comment: Right. See edits; the .css file in that directory becomes inaccessible (404). Well, it seems like my web.config had some stuff that blocked it. Now it's fixed.